# Are items placed in an unordered_map stored in the stack or the heap?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class MyOtherClass{
     std::unordered_map<int, std::multimap<int, MyClass*>> _xy;

     void putObject(int x,int y,MyClass* obj);
     void containsXkey(int x){
         bool found = false;
         std::unordered_map<int,std::multi map<int,MyClass*>>::const_iterator index = _xy.find(x);

         if(index = _xy.end(){
               found = false;
         }else{
               found = true;
         }

          return found;
     }
}
```

Say I want to write a function to place a MyClass at coordinates (2,3), then I would do something like this:

```
void putObject(int x, int y, MyClass* obj){
    if(!containsXKey(x){
          //Since it doesn't contain an empty multimap, I'm creating one.
          std::multimap<int, MyClass*> foo; //This is created on the stack
          _xy[x] = foo; //What happens here ?
    }

    std::multimap<int,MyClass*>& foo = _xy[x];
    foo.insert(y,obj);
}
```

So my question is: Initially there are no entries in the `unordered_map`, so the first time I want to add an item at a particular key, I need to create a `multimap`. The `multimap` is created on the stack. So what happens when I assign it to the key ? Is it making a copy ? Where is it being stored ?

Comment: There's no such things like _stack_ or _heap_. `std::unordered_map` uses dynamic memory allocation to store map items (as most other standard containers do).

Comment: So what happens to the multimap  that I created ?

Comment: Looks like it's copied to `_xy[x]`.

Comment: The `std::multimap` object you created is on the stack. The objects it refers to are necessarily in the heap, as they are added dynamically. @πάντα ῥεῖ's comment starting 'there is no such thing' is not correct. Dynamic memory is in the heap; local objects are on the stack.

Comment: Maybe πάντα ῥεῖ means that the standard does not define such terms as the stack and the heap?

Comment: I'm a bit confused - It looks to me that the multi map I create is on the stack, and contents (which is a pointer, should be on the heap). It seems to me that what is actually stored in the unordedered_map is a copy of the multimap which is in the heap.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Maybe he does, but it still isn't correct. Maybe there are different terms for it in the standards, but 'no such thing' is patently wrong.

Comment: @John You should note that there's actually no allocation done for the value type, at least not in the snippet of code you show.

Comment: @EJP If the standard doesn't mention stack or heap, then "no such thing" is the correct phrase to describe the situation. You can identify some other thing in the standard and call it "the stack", but this doesn't mean the standard now contains "the stack". Only your interpretation does.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not sure what you mean. Are you talking about obj ?

Comment: @John Yes, I meant `obj`. It's just a pointer copied around. It's probably better to use a `std::unique_ptr<MyClass>` or such.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thats correct, it is just a pointer which is copied around, and is "owned" by another class. This class is just for bookkeeping and easy lookups.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like all the dynamic sized containers, the map containers keep their elements on the dynamic memory storage* (the "heap"**).
the object itself may sit on the stack, heap or so, but inside the object there may be sub-objects or pointers that points to dynamic memory.

> So what happens when I assign it to the key?

the map will make sure the internal buffer can hold another key-value pair, if not, it will expand to support a storage for one more element.

> Is it making a copy?

it depends on how the key/value was passed to the map. if the key/value supports move semantics and the key was passed as r-value-reference, it will not get copied but *moved* instead. but if the class does not support move semantics or the key was passed as const reference, it will get copied.

> Where is it being stored ?

The standard does not mandate how the map should be implemented internally, so every library may implement it how-ever it likes. Microsoft `std::unordered_map` keeps the key-values pair in a linked list, other libraries may choose to keep the map elements in a vector or so.

```
      std::multimap<int, MyClass*> foo; //This is created on the stack
      _xy[x] = foo; //What happens here ?
```

in this case, `foo` is created on the stack. the operator `[]` itself creates a default created `std::multimap` on the heap, then the operator `=` copies the content of `foo` (which are non) into `_xy[y]`.

*assuming the map uses the standard allocator, one can set specific allocator which allocates memory from other storage.

** The standard does not state words like "stack" and "heap" directly, but states the following terms : automatic storage ("the stack"), dynamic storage ("the heap"), static storage ("the data segment"), and thread storage ("TLS").

Comment: With reference to my code sample, would it be correct to say that the multi map which is created in the if block, is on the stack, and what is actually stored in the unordered_map is a copy which is on the heap ?